# How can I change capital letter to lower case letters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, uppercase, lowercase

While analyzing the apache access log on logstash, there is something not distinguishable between upper and lower case letters.  The reason of compare between uppercase and lowercase letters is because kibana must display uri request values.
So I tried something like this.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "message" ]
  }
}
```

Restarting after put mutate in filter, does not work properly.

How can I solve this problem?